# R-package compatible with the psce-package when one want to export regression tables

Tags: html, r, texreg

I am wondering if there is any R-package out there which is compatible with the psce-package when wanting to create html-files out of regression tables?

I have used the `pcse()` function to implement panel corrected standard errors in the regression. Now, when I want to export my table, using the `texreg-` or the `stargazer` package results in error.
This is the code that I am trying to use:

```
htmlreg(Model6_reg_pcse, file = "Model6_regression.html")
```

This is the  error message that shows:

> "Error in extract(l[[i]], ...) :
> Neither texreg nor broom supports models of class pcse."

Is there a package which supports class `psce`?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the package `pcse` is a package, that can implement this, as it says in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcse/pcse.pdf.

You can simply type

```
library(pcse)

help(pcse)
```

to find something on it. But firstly, you should install the *package*, and you can simply type `install.packages("pcse")`. And in order for this to work correctly if you are in R studio, you have to go to *packages -> search bar -> type pcse -> mark the box pcse* and you can use the resources.

However, for you to use *html* resources, you have to do the same process with the package `texreg`. You can just type `library(texreg)` and then your code, before you should have typed `install.packages("texreg")`. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I have already installed both of these packages, but it does not seems like they are compatible with each other. Meaning I cannot save files using ```texreg``` functions, as I have implemented ```pcse```in my analysis.

Comment: If it helped, it's cool to upvote, if it didn't I can explain better.